# Find an orthogonal matrix $W$ such that $WR$ is symmetric for a given triangular matrix $R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Basically this is a part of a long algorithm to calculate some matrix properties.

Given an upper triangular square matrix $R$, how can I find an orthonormal matrix $W$ (possibly iteratively) such that $WR$ is square and symmetric?

I have tried using something like Givens rotations in order to get rid of elements above the diagonal. Yet, I noticed that it results in creating some elements below the diagonal. So, this does not work.